# Use twig to display data from youtube feed

Tags: php, xml, twig

I'm all new to [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) and I got involved in this project where I'm forced to figure a solution out. And that's why I had to ask this question here.

I want to display the videos on a youtube playlist which is easy enough when it comes to pure PHP and the use of (for example) `simplexml_load_file($feed)`.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
foreach ($xml->entry as $key => $x) {
    $title = $x->title;
    $id = $x->children('yt', True)->videoId;
    $uri = $x->author->uri;
    $desc = $x->children('media', True)->group->description;
}
```

But since I know little to nothing about twig I can't really get an understanding how to do the similar thing. Or if it is even possible.

Comment: Twig is not that hard to learn - and if you need to use it on a regular basis, you should use this first task as one to learn Twig

Comment: Twig as a template *language* is used to display stuff. Meaning you compile the data you want (e.g. with the code you have) and have it rendered via twig mechanisms. So the answer would be, no you can't to that in twig, because you shouldn't.

Comment: @NicoHaase i will not use it on a regular basis. Just to try to fix this one problem for a customer! :)

Comment: @Yoshi thanks! That is a answer as good as any. Just want to know if i shall keep on spending my time on trying to solve this of if we should go for another solution. :)

Comment: That really depends. If all your *displaying code* uses twig, then yes use twig here as well. But otherwise, twig will not add any benefit if it's a *one-time-use thing*.

Comment: @Yoshi yeah this whole project uses twig to display data. I just want to read a feed and display it's content and thought it should work even though i knew nothing about twig itself! :)

Comment: Well then the answer is clear. Yes use twig here as well. But realize that you don't *do* this *in twig*, you still compile your data in plain php (or whatever framework you use) and then use twig to display that data.

Comment: @Yoshi ok, sweet! thanks! 
Best practice is to call the php-file from the twig file and somehow declare the php-array into a twig-array?

Comment: That would surprise me. The usual flow would be that whatever code that handles the request, will compile the data and pass it to the twig template. But if you want this to be some kind of widget (meaning: independent of the request, but *includable* in other templates) then you should look into [Extending Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html) (probably a [function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#id2)).